# Summation Proof For $ Y_{ij} - \bar Y_j $

Tags: statistics, summation, self-learning, regression

Currently trying to prove that the sum of squares error can be partitioned into SSPE and SSLF.

$ SSE = \sum_{j=1}^c \sum_{i=1}^{nj} (Y_{ij}- \hat Y_{ij})^2 =  \sum_{j=1}^c \sum_{i=1}^{nj} (Y_{ij}- \bar Y_{j})^2 + \sum_{j=1}^c \sum_{i=1}^{nj} (\bar Y_{j}- \hat Y_{ij})^2 $

Ive gotten to the point where i have to show
$ \sum_{i=1}^{nj} (Y_{ij}- \bar Y_{j}) =0 $

Is this correct? 
$ \sum_{i=1}^{nj} Y_{ij} - \sum_{i=1}^{nj} \bar Y_j = n_j \bar Y_j - n_j \bar Y_j = 0 $

This is probably very simple but I cannot seem to figure it out.

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst care to explain why

Comment: $\sum_{i=1}^{nj}(Y_{ij}-\bar{Y}_j) = n_j \bar{Y_j}-n_j \bar{Y}_j = 0 $, so yes all good.